# Weird behaviour in C++

Tags: c++, utf-16

This program instead of printing all the three characters, prints only one. Why does it behave that way?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string a("   ");
    a[0] = (char)65519; //Supposed to be UTF 16 characters
    a[1] = (char)65471;
    a[2] = (char)65469;

    //prints �
    cout << a << std::endl;

    //prints �
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) 
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I can understand the understand the � character being printed because my charset does not have a valid glyph/representation for it, but why isn't 3 such characters are printed but only one? And why does it happen even if I use a for loop?

EDIT: From the comments below, I am not caring about the loss of information. I know I am typecasting an integer(32 bit) to a char(8 bit) and that I am losing information. What I am concerned about is, why doesn't it print all three characters but prints only one?

Comment: 65519 is too big to fit into char.

Comment: You probably want a `std::u16string` and you shouldn't cast to `char`.

Comment: I get three chararters `ï¿½` with g++ 4.8.2 on linux xterm

Comment: You are not printing UTF-16. You are converting 16 bit values into char (loosing half the data in the process) and then printing the result as a string. For 16 bit values, you would need to use `std::wcout` and `std::wstring` and `wchar_t` (instead of `char`) - and your `char` conversions would become unnecessary.

Comment: @NeilKirk But `(char)65519` isn't :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After throwing away half of each 16-bit value, the remaining 8-bit values are:

```
0xef 0xbf 0xbd
```

Since these are not ASCII values (which are in the range of `0x00` to `0x7f`), the output depends on how your terminal interprets non-ASCII values. One common encoding is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), and these three values happen to form a valid UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode [replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm), which is displayed as �.

Answer (score 2):

```
a[0] = (char)65519;
```

Oh, please, never write things like this. Don't forget that char contains one byte so the largest value of char is 127. You can also write (char)255 (that means -1 for signed char or 255 for unsigned) but no more than 255.

For Unicode write the following

```
wstring a(L"   ");
a[0] = (wchar_t)65519; //Supposed to be UTF 16 characters
a[1] = (wchar_t)65471;
a[2] = (wchar_t)65469;
```

Comment: BTW, `char` may be implemented as `unsigned` or `signed` or `char`, and it is compiler dependent.  So, `char` may have a range of 0..255.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, it may, but 99% of the platforms you're likely to use will have it `signed`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, thank you for the remark. Anyway, you can use numbers up to 255 for signed char too.